# AttributeError: 'Fraction' object has no attribute 'denom'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributeerror, fractions

The below code is part of a fraction calculator, I want my code to go to my gcd function from my **init** so that I can pass the result as a gcd of the fraction to simplify it, I don't know if the below way is correct to do so.

```
class Fraction:


    def __init__(self, num, denom) -> None:  
    
        self.num = self.denom = self.gcd()
        if self.denom < 0:
            self.denom = abs(self.denom)
            self.num = -1*self.num
        elif self.denom == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError("cansnot divide by zero")

    def gcd(self):

        while self.denom != 0: 
            self.num,self.denom = self.denom,self.num%self.denom
        return abs(self.num)   

def get_fraction() -> Fraction:

    while True:
        num: str = input("Enter the numerator")
        denom: str = input("Enter the denominator")
        try:
            a = int(num)
            b = int(denom)
            return Fraction(a, b)
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter valid numerator and denominator")

def compute(f1: Fraction, operator: str, f2: Fraction) -> None:

    okay = True
    if operator == '+':
        result = f1.__add__(f2)

    elif operator == '-':
        result = f1.__sub__(f2)

    elif operator == '*':
        result = f1.__mul__(f2)

    elif operator == '/':
        result = f1.__truediv__(f2)

    else:
        print(operator, " is an unrecognized operator")
        okay = False

    if okay == True:
        print(f"{f1} {operator} {f2} = {result}")

def main() -> None:

"""Main menu"""

    print("Welcome to the Fraction Calculator! ")
    while True:
        print('Press Q to quit or any other key to start')
        z = input("Start or Quit?")
        if z == 'Q' or z == 'q':
            exit()
        else:
            f1: Fraction = get_fraction()
            operator: str = input("Operation (+, -, *, / , = , < , > , <= ,>= , != ): ")
            f2: Fraction = get_fraction()
            try:
                compute(f1, operator, f2)
            except ZeroDivisionError as e:
                print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

When I execute this I get the below error:

```
while self.denom != 0:
AttributeError: 'Fraction' object has no attribute 'denom'
```

I am not sure why this message is thrown.

Comment: If denom is greater than 0 you never set `self.denom`

Comment: `__init__` calls `self.gcd()` before `self.denom` is set.  Presumably you want to set `self.denom = denom` and also set `self.num = num` at the top of `__init__`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I added self.num=num and self.denom=denom. But, it just shows the output as cannot divide by zero for any fraction I add.

Comment: Show us how you're creating the fraction instance.

Comment: hi sorry I'm new here, if I edit the original post will you be able to see it?

Comment: I have edited it